# Incrementing by one

Tags: prolog

This is part of a larger problem, so I might just be thinking about this the wrong way. But here goes.

I have the following "transition" rule:

```
//if in state(A,B,C), move to state C
trans( state(A, B, C), state(A, B, D is C + 1), added_one).
```

I am trying to come up with a way to add 1 to C.

Some more background: I am doing a "crossing" problem, I.E. get these animals across a river without breaking a set of rules. C is the number of animals in the boat, which cannot surpass 2 (I have a different rule to handle <= 2 check).

Currently, the way I have it setup does not ever seem to use D. When I use the "trace" function, D is always a don't care value.

How should I go about this? Thank you.

EDIT: Code.

```
initial( state(  3,  3,  1,  0,  0,  0, 0) ).
final(   state(  0,  0,  0,  3,  3,  1, 0) ).

//BCpp stands for boatcount++.
BCpp is BoatCount + 1,
trans(state( 2, LF, 1, RH, RF, 0 , BoatCount) , state(1, LF, 1, RH, RF, 0, BCpp), hen_in_left_boat).

BCpp is BoatCount + 1,
trans(state( 1, LF, 1, RH, RF, 0 , BoatCount) , state(0, LF, 1, RH, RF, 0, BCpp), hen_in_left_boat).

//and so on for a bunch of transitions.
//the code produces an error at the first line "BCpp is BoatCount + 1,"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out through guess and check based off of @mbratch's answer.

```
D is C + 1,
trans(state(A, B, C), state(A, B, D), added_one).
```

was throwing an error, so I switched it to:

```
trans(state(A, B, C), state(A, B, D) ) :- D is C + 1.
```

It is now running correctly. Well, this part anyway :(

Comment: OK. It was unclear in your original problem that this was what you were trying to achieve. Feel free to post a new problem statement in SO for new problems you may have.